# Draw an invisible control on a canvas in Delphi

Tags: delphi, draw, invisible

I made a calendar component for Delphi. Now I want to add a visual effect to it while changing months (like Windows Vista standard calendar).

Now I want to create an invisible duplicate of the component and draw that one on the canvas to use it for the visual effect. I tried `BitBlt` function but it does not work because the control is invisible. Is there any way to draw an invisible control on a canvas?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand My problem is how to draw control on TBitmap.

Comment: I assume you need the "scroll" effect between two months. How's a second control being of any help with that?

Comment: @Ngln, if the hidden control is another calendar control, and it's already set to the next month, then you can get an image of the visible control and put it next to an image of the invisible control. Now animate that image across the visible control while you change the visible control's current month to match the hidden one.

Comment: @Rob Ah, I understand. Sounds obese though.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @NGLN: obese? What Dutch word did you have in mind when you came up with obese? Mystified...

Comment: @Marjan "Zwaarlijvig", ie rather heavy for the task: I need one, let's make two...

Comment: +1 for pointing out obese code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the control's [`PaintTo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.PaintTo) method. That's for descendants of `TWinControl`.

I don't see an analogous method for `TGraphicControl` descendants, but since those always require a `TWinControl` parent, you could just call `PaintTo` on the parent control to get an image of the `TGraphicControl` child.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Rob's [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12584924/757830), may I present two alternatives?

1. The arrows and month name do not seem to scroll, so let's call them the header of the component and make it a subcontrol of the component. Subsequently, make the days a subcontrol too. Now it is possible to place two *day-controls* adjacent to the one shown. Because they are beyond the bounds of the component, these aside placed day-controls are hidden, but become visible as soon as they move. At the end of the scroll operation, move the outmost to the other side and set its month appropriately.
2. Move the painting of the days to a separate routine with a month-like parameter. When scrolling, call that routine twice.